# Rails 7 - uninitialized constant Impressionist::Engine::ImpressionistController (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, impressionist

After upgrading to rails 7 I'm getting below error with the impressionist gem. When I start my local server.
Any help, please?

```
uninitialized constant Impressionist::Engine::ImpressionistController (NameError)
```

- ruby "~> 3.0.1"
- gem "rails", "~> 7.0.0"
- gem "impressionist", git:
  "https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist
  I did bundle install and restarted rails server.

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
/Users/XXXX/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bundler/gems/impressionist-e0db056a2ac0/lib/impressionist/engine.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>': uninitialized constant Impressionist::Engine::ImpressionistController (NameError)
        from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in on_load'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `on_load'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bundler/gems/impressionist-e0db056a2ac0/lib/impressionist/engine.rb:14:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/xxxx/Dev/pro/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.3/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require_relative'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:76:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:36:in `start'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? Maybe it has something to do with constant lookup and [This File](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/blob/master/lib/impressionist/engine.rb) where the application is unable to resolve `::Impressionist::ImpressionistController` when it is referenced merely as `ImpressionistController` or maybe the "app" directory structure is not loading in for some reason

Comment: @engineersmnky I have updated my question with the error log

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @Daniel, no I couldn't fix it. I have disabled the gem in my app for now until I see it fixed here https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/issues/302

Comment: This is crazy, I got this same error yesterday, came here was almost about to give up, then I did something and can't quite remember, but its definitely nothing crazy, perhaps just using `gem 'impressionist'` and it worked fine until today after I installed another gem to add OTP with Devise. WTF

And I say 'nothing crazy' since I just rechecked the commit and the installation is verbatim whats on the gem readme.

BTW, Rails 7.0.1 - Ruby 3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```rb
# add to application.rb at the top
impressionist_dir = Gem::Specification.find_by_name('impressionist').gem_dir
require File.join(impressionist_dir, '/app/controllers/impressionist_controller.rb')
```